# Google Firestore retention policy

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Google firestore as my noSql database for a nodejs api. I would like to know if there is a way to configure a retention policy for data. I want to automatically delete old document, for example delete old documents which are 30 days old.

Thanks

Comment: You have to do this yourself. You can use Firebase functions or equivalent to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration or setting for this.  You will have to arrange for some other process to query for and delete documents that meet the criteria for deletion.  This would be possible with a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), for example, that you write for yourself.  Or you can [use Cloud Tasks to schedule individual document deletes](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there was a simple configuration for doing that like on Azure. I will write a scheduled function for that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that you can start from:

```js
export default FirebaseFunctions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 hours').onRun(async (context) => {
  const now = Date.now()
  const DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  const batchSize = 500

  // Delete events older than 30 DAYS
  const events = await FirebaseFirestore.collection('events')
    .where('created_at', '<', now - 30 * DAYS)
    .limit(batchSize)
    .get()

  console.log(`Found ${events.size} events`)

  if (events.size > 0) {
    await deleteBatch(events.docs)
    console.log(`Deleted ${events.size} events`)
    return // stop execution here
  }
}
```